# How to Copy OTP in the gmail and paste it to the field in the Mobile apk using Katalon

Tags: android, email, web, mobile, katalon

How to get and Copy OTP in the gmail and paste it to the field in the Mobile apk using Katalon

Hi, i am writing a Katalon script in mobile testing. I must copy OTP that i get from gmail and copy it to the field in Mobile apk. I don't know how to get OTP from gmail, copy it and paste it to the field in Mobile apk. How
Please help me.

Thank you

I have an access to the gmail account.

Comment: And .. what is OTP to begin with?

Comment: And what would be 'in the gmail'? Where would that be? And dont you just mean 'in the email'?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are doing. What is the context?

Comment: The OP needs to fetch a received OTP (One Time Password) in an email via Gmail & copy it to the clipboard & then paste it to a TextField. I don't think this is achievable directly. One can however use the `NotificationListenerService` & filter the received emails & scan the content with some regex logic. But seems like an overkill though.

Comment: I'm writing a katalon script from mobile android testing. One of the test step, i must entered the OTP. The time that i got to entered the OTP was 1 minute. I must got the OTP from email inbox. I have an access to open the email. What should i do? Can you describe what the actions or scripts i must add in katalon? fyi i used katalon 8.6.8

Comment: Here are my logic of the steps 1. Open the gmail 2. Click the inbox 3.open the top message or the newest message 4. Copy the OTP. My question is how to copy or get the OTP from email and then paste it to the field OTP in mobile android?